# Create a new PowerShell string containing defined substrings

Tags: string, variables, powershell

I've found myriad methods to retrieve data FROM a string with substrings, but what I want to do is create a **new** string that **contains substrings**. The reason for this is that I want to pass that string to a CSV through the `Export-CSV` cmdlet. This is in a PowerShell Forms created app.

So the plan would be to
1). Read the contents of each text box:
(e.g. `$endusername.text` `$endusernumber.text` `$locationname.text`)

2). Store those into a new string with substrings 
(`$formoutput.endusername` `$formoutput.endusernumber` `$formoutput.locationname`)

3). Output the string to a .CSV

```
Export-CSV -InputObject $formoutput "c:\output\formoutput.csv"
```

Basically, if I take any existing cmdlet (say, `Get-Mailbox`), store its output as a string, and then pass that string through the `Export-CSV` in the way explained above, it performs exactly the way I like - creating a .CSV with each of the substrings as a column, and the contents of that substring in the appropriately headed column. I just want to be able to do that with a string containing substrings that I define.

Comment: You can create an object that contains string. [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15388367/create-custom-psobject-powershell-2-0?answertab=active#tab-top) is one way to handle it. If you have newer versions of powershell 3.0+ you can use `[pscustomobject]`. Either of these will export to CSV easily. Unless you want to add anything to `Get-Mailbox` you can export that data right away `Get-Mailbox -Identity user | Select Name,EmailAddress | Export-Csv "c:\filepath.csv" -NoTypeInformation`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing nomenclature a little bit. It sounds like what you want is a custom object not a string. Here is some pseudo-code to get you going in the right direction:

```
$formOutput = New-Object PsCustomObject -Property @{'EndUserName' = $endUserName.Text;
                                                    'EndUserNumber' = $endUserNumber.Text;
                                                    'LocationName' = $locatioName.Text}
$formOutput | Export-CSV .\FileName.csv -NoTypeHeader
```